# Using an iterator without its container

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am mixing some C and C++ libraries and have only a single pointer available to do some work in a callback function.  All I need to do is iterate through a vector.  Here's a simplified, untested example:

```
bool call_back(void* data){
  done=...
  if (!done) cout << *data++ << endl;
  return done;
}
```

Note that this function is in an `extern "C"` block in C++.  `call_back` will be called until true is returned.  I want it to cout the next element each time it's called.  `data` is a pointer to something that I can pass from elsewhere in the code (an iterator in the above example, but can be anything).  Something from `data` will likely be used to calculate `done`.  I see two obvious options to give to `data`:

1. Have `data` point to my vector.
2. Have `data` point to an iterator of my vector.

I can't use an iterator without having the .end() method available, right?  I can't use a vector alone (unless maybe I start removing its data).  I could make a struct with both vector and iterator, but is there a better way?  What would you do?

Comment: Will this function be called from C++ code only?

Comment: Yes, I expect it to always be an extern "C" within a C++ code file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not have data point to a structure with all the information you need.

The point about the old "C" style callbacks is that a void* can point to any object. Your callback function knows what the type is, but it can be anything.

```
typedef struct Plop
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator begin;
    std::vector<int>::iterator end;
} Plop;

bool call_back(void* data)
{
    // Or static_cast<> for the pedantic.
    // I like reinterpret_cast<> because it is a clue to humans that this is dangerious
    // and as long as the object was originally a Plop* pointer it is guaranteed to work.
    Plop*   info = reinterpret_cast<Plop*>(data);

    bool    done= info.begin == info.end;

    if (!done) cout << *data++ << endl;
    return done;
}
```

Comment: I really wanted to avoid a new struct just for this function.  Interesting comments about casting.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't use an iterator without having the .end() method available, right?

No. You can use the iterator with the result of invoking the .end() function. You don't need to keep calling the .end() function... so if you just store both iterators, then you're golden.

> I can't use a vector alone (unless maybe I start removing its data).

Not alone, but with a std::size_t index then that's all you would need.

> I could make a struct with both vector and iterator, but is there a better way? What would you do?

If you don't have to worry about supporting other container types, then I would use:

```
 template<typename T> struct CALLBACK_DATA
 {
      std::vector<T>* array;
      std::size_t index;
 };
```

If you might have to support multiple container types, then I would use:

```
 template<typename T> struct CALLBACK_DATA
 {
     typedef std::vector<T> container_type;
     typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;
     const_iterator current;
     const_iterator end;
 };
```

So, yeah, I would either pass the vector and an index or a pair of iterators, and I would construct a struct to hold the data. If you want to avoid creating a struct, then you could use `std::pair`, however I personally think it is more readable to simply create a custom struct to hold this information.

Answer (score 0):

How about dereferencing the iterator and passing it's value to `call_back`? Then increment it after the function returns?